# GZWeb: Open and Save Worlds

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm learning to use gzweb, the web client for Gazebo, and I'm quite a fan. However, it seems that documentation on it is rather lacking, and I can't figure out the simplest task. How can I open and save worlds on the server? Is there a way to open and save them from the web client, or does it have to be done on the server somehow?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8349/gzweb:-open-and-save-worlds/) by [Jordan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1165/jordan/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 25 on 2015-03-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Opening worlds can only be done server-side via the command line for now. Starting `gzserver` like this for example:

```
gzserver <path>/my_world.world
```

For now, I think the only way to save the world is through `gzclient`. You can create your world on `GzWeb`, then open a `gzclient` on a new terminal and do `File -> Save World As`.

I just created an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gzweb/issue/63/add-save-world-option) for saving worlds on GzWeb's client-side.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jordan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1165/jordan/) on 2015-03-31**:
Excellent, thank you. Such fast and helpful responses in this community!